# How can I add a tab at the top of the teamcity main page

Tags: java, plugins, teamcity, teamcity-6

We're trying to add a new tab on the top of teamcity's main page next to the Projects/My Changes/Agents/Build Queue area.

Is there any way to do this with the current API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a part of OpenAPI. But you can try the following Javascript code:

```
  topNavPane.addTab("customTab", {
    caption: "Tab title",
    url: "<c:url value="/your_controller.html"/>"
  });
```

You'll have to wright implementation of your_controller, obviously.
In your JSP view, you'll probably want to use page.tag, which is common base for TeamCity pages.